# Extension of Baire's Theorem

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space, $\kappa$ be a cardinal number, such that there exists a dense subset $A\subseteq X$ of cardinality $\kappa$ but there does not exist a dense subset $A'\subseteq X$ of cardinality less than $\kappa$.

Now, suppose that $X$ is a metric space which satisfies the above property for $\kappa\geq \aleph_0$.  In this generality is there a Baire-type theorem stating that if $(A_{i})_{i \in I}$ is a collection of dense open subsets of $X$ each of Cardinality at most $\kappa$ and $I$ is of cardinality $\kappa$ then 
$
\cap_{i \in I} A_i \neq \emptyset?
$

Comment: It's false for $\kappa=\aleph_0$, isn't it? Because not every separable topological space is a Baire space? Are you assuming $\kappa\gt\aleph_0$?

Comment: I would need $X$ to be metric and $\kappa\geq \aleph_0$.  (So in particular $X$ is a Baire space, in the classical sense but it $\kappa>\aleph_0$ then it would be non-separable).

Comment: I vaguely recall stronger version of BCT under [Martin's axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin%27s_axiom). You can try to search for [strong Baire category theorem](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=%22strong+Baire+category+theorem%22). (I hope somebody else will be able to say a bit more about this.)

Comment: Related: [Is there a suitably generalized Baire property for topological spaces of arbitrary cardinalities?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/151409/15780) I've come across several papers on this theme, but unfortunately this is not something I've ever paid attention to and thus I don't have any specific references written down anywhere. The papers I'm thinking of were mostly written independently of each other and were widely scattered in the mathematical literature. For example, I think some might have been short notes in Doklady Akademii Nauk from the 1960s and/or 1970s.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Such a hypothetical Baire theorem is not true: for every cardinal $\kappa$ of uncountable cofinality and any cofinal subset $C\subset \kappa$ of cardinality $|C|=\mathrm{cf}(\kappa)$, the Hilbert space $\ell_2(\kappa)$ of density $\kappa$ is a complete metric space that can be written as the union $\bigcup_{\alpha\in C}\ell_2(\alpha)$ of $\mathrm{cf}(\kappa)$ many closed nowhere dense subsets $\ell_2(\alpha)=\{x\in\ell_2(\kappa):x^{-1}(\mathbb R\setminus\{0\})\subset [0,\alpha)\}$. Then the intersection $\bigcap_{\alpha\in C}U_\alpha$ of the dense open sets $U_\alpha=\ell_2(\kappa)\setminus\ell_2(\alpha)$ is empty.

The same concerns the closed unit ball $B$ of $\ell_2(\kappa)$. In the weak topology, $B$ is (uniform Eberlein) compact, which can be written as the union of $\mathrm{cf}(\kappa)$ many closed nowhere dense subsets. So, the Baire Theorem does not extend even to the intersection of $\aleph_1$ many dense open sets in nice (namely, uniform Eberlein) compact spaces.

On the other hand, there are some extensions of the Baire Theorem for topological spaces of countable cellularity, but a metrizable space has countable cellularity if and only if it is separable, so such extensions do not concern metrizable spaces. Namely, the Martin's Axiom is equivalent to the statement:

> For any compact Hausdorff space $K$ of countable cellularity, the intersection of less than continuum many dense open sets in $K$ is not empty.

As a first reading of this topic, you can look at section 1 called "Topology of MA" of the survey paper "Versions of Martin's Axiom" of William Weiss in "Handbook of Set-Theoretic Topology" published by Elsevier in far 1984.

Also there exists a well-known cardinal characteristic $\mathrm{cov}(\mathcal M)$ of the continuum, equal to the smallest number of open dense subsets in the real line whose intersection is empty. The value of $\mathrm{cov}(\mathcal M)$ is between $\omega_1$ and $\mathfrak c$, but its exact position in the segment 
$[\omega_1,\mathfrak c]$ depends on additional axioms of Set Theory. The cardinal $\mathrm{cov}(\mathcal M)$ is one of 10 cardinal characteristics of the continuum, composing the famous [Cichon's Diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cicho%C5%84%27s_diagram).

Comment: This is very interesting.  Would you happen to have a reference for each of the latter two points.  I'd like to look into it in more detail.

Comment: @MrMMS I have added references to my answer.

Comment: I've been reading the "Topology of MA" you recommended and I'm wondering one thing.  Similarly to the classical reformulations of Baire's Theorem is MA equivalent to the following statement:

If X is of countable cellularity is a Baire space (ie: each countable collection of open dense subsets has a non-empty intersection)?

Comment: Conclusions for Baire and nonmeager usually are equivalence, since a topological space $X$ is nonmeager if and only if  $X$ contains an open Baire subspace.

Comment: Perfect this has been really helpful.  Im going through the GMA now and seeing how I can use it.  Thank you.  Also, I'm curious are there known examples of function spaces which are non-metric and of countable cellularity?

Comment: @MrMMS It is well-known that arbitrary Tychonoff product of separable spaces is countably cellular. So for any set $X$ the space $\mathbb R^X$ of all real-valued functions on $X$ with the topology of pointwise convergence is countably cellular. Since the countable cellularity is preserved by dense subspaces, the space $C_p(X)\subset \mathbb R^X$ of continuous functions on any Tychonoff space $X$ has countable cellularity as well as many subspace of $C_p(X)$, for example smooth functions (if $X$ has a smoothness structure).

Comment: Thank you Banach, this helps a lot.  With this direction, I'll read up on the details.

Comment: @MrMMS You are welcome. Good luck then!